# Not able to display 'current date minus one month' as default in bootstrap date picker on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, datepicker

I have two datepickers on my page and would like to display the **current date** in one of them and **current date minus one month** in the second date picker.

I was able to accomplish to display the current date successfully in one of them  but could not get the other one working.

This is what I tried using `JQuery`.

**my-date-picker.js**

```
$('#fraud-end-date-picker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() - 1, new Date().getDay()),
});

$('#fraud-end-date-picker').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: true
});
```

**my-page.html**

```
<!--Date Picker -->
      <!--From Date-->
      <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top:8px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='fraud-start-date-picker'>
            <%= text_field_tag :fraud_start_time, params[:fraud_start_time], class: 'form-control input-style ' %>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--To Date-->
      <div class="col-md-2" style="padding-top:8px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='fraud-end-date-picker'>
            <%= text_field_tag :fraud_end_time, params[:fraud_end_time], class: 'form-control input-style ' %>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Instead of all that logic to get one month prior date, try:  var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);

Comment: Tried that, but nothing got displayed in the date picker.

Comment: Do I need to fire any 'update' event in JQuery in order to make this change visible ?

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: Note that *getDay* returns the day in the week (0 to 6). In the context of the OP, it should probably be replaced with *getDate*. Also, when subtracting one month from dates like 31 July, the result is 31 June which rolls over to 1 July (even worse for March). You need to include logic to deal with that.

Comment: Try to refer to [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/ark7ryxk/2/). But sad to say is all I got is onSelect.